# Can netbeans highlight deprecated PHP constructs

Tags: netbeans

I have NetBeans 20 (on Windows) set to PHP 8.3 standard.

I was hoping NetBeans might flag deprecated constructs - such as the use of ${var} instead of {$var} but it doesn't seem to do this.

Is this because of a setting that I need to change, or is it not something that NetBeans can do?

- Monathan